# Detect extreme value vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, standard-deviation

I have a vector of values (delays) like this {2,4,6,3,4,5,6,4,..} in C++. My objective is to detect when a new value is an extreme value - for example, 96. I am trying to come up with a general check to detect instead of putting specific numerical checks.

By extreme value I mean 96 would be X times larger than 2 or 3 or 4. However, if I have delays as {15,23,10,26,..} and then a value 550, which is Y times larger than normal - I want to detect.

I need to start with the standard deviation, but not sure about the best approach further.

Thank you.

Comment: How many values will you have in the vector *before* you start thinking about what is extreme or not?

Comment: What is the question? I guess you expect us to give you a metric for a extreme value, but that highly depends on the context and purpose.

Comment: First of all you need to define *what* an "extreme" value is. If you have that definition, then it's easy to code up a check for it.

Comment: Sorry about that - updated the question.

Comment: Do you expect these delays to be always around some time invariant constant value? Or could these delays slowly increase over some time, then slowly decrease again?

Comment: @DanielJour: You going to answer if the OP comes back and tells you that there is a statistically significant underlying drift function? **Woof!** I'd upvote that.

Comment: You may want to ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) what *kind* of extrema testing is appropriate, then, when you know *what* to implement, you can ask here for help if you get stuck with the *how*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of any other statistical information, compute the *mean* and the *standard deviation of the mean* of your existing data, and if the new point is more than 3 standard deviations of the mean outside that mean, then don't add it.

After you have a certain number of points so you can be reasonably sure that the central limit theorem has started to work its magic (20 points as a rule of thumb, especially as "delays" implies "Poisson" on first glance), develop an algorithm to eliminate any outliers that might have been added to the initial set. Do that by considering each added point in turn - eliminate it, and see it matches the criteria for inclusion. This step is important: it's designed to fail an outlier that's introduced early; e.g. {2, 96, 4, 6, 3, 4, 5}. For really hostile data you might need to increase the dimensionality of that algorithm.

This is a tricky science - you'll have to calibrate this to suit your requirements but what I suggest will get you started.